# Bash shell prompt: where is $RET?

Tags: bash

I was reading this https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Color_Bash_Prompt
and ended up with the following:

```
# Stores the status of each command in $RET
PROMPT_COMMAND='RET=$?;'

# A colour.
RED_SHELL='\e[0;36m'

# Prints "Status 1" if RET is 1, for example.
RET_VISUALISE='$(if [[ $RET != 0 ]]; then echo -ne "Status \[$RED_SHELL\]$RET\n" && RET=0; fi;)'

# What to print for each prompt.
PS1="$RET_VISUALISE\[\e]0;\w\a\]\n\[\e[32m\]\u@\h \t \[\e[33m\]\w\[\e[0m\]\n\$ "
```

This does almost what I want, except when I press Enter,Enter,Enter multiple times after a command that returned status != 0. In this case it prints "Status 1" every time I press Enter.

This is what the `&& RET=0;` part was supposed to get rid of.

Also, I don't understand why `env | grep RET` only shows the `PS1` contents. What is the scope of `$RET` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overriding your `RET=0` with `RET=$?` when the next prompt is printed without having executed a command in between. `$?` returns the last executed command's return value, and that's still `1`.

Bash allows you to trap errors in executed commands and execute code in response to that (once):

```
function err_handle {
    RET=$?
    if [[ $RET != 0 ]]; then
        echo -ne "Status $RED_SHELL$RET\n"
    fi
}
trap 'err_handle' ERR
```

Comment: Right, I see! So the way it seems now is that $RET only exists for a relatively short amount of time, while the shell is printing the prompt. But how to think about this? Does this happen within some function, so that the scope of $RET is local to that function?

Comment: @EvgeniSergeev Read the first paragraph again. You could also run `set -x` which enables tracing. When you just press enter (no command), `RET=$?` assigns the return code of the *last executed function* again, so setting it to `0` just gets overridden. And in fact, since you set it *within a subshell*, the assignment isn't propagated back to the outside scope anyway. Example: `FOO=bar ; echo $FOO ; BAZ=$( FOO=baz ; echo $FOO ) ; echo $FOO ; echo $BAZ`. As I wrote before, it doesn't matter, since `RET=$?` will just assign the same (error) return code again. Just try my solution and move on.

Comment: Heh, I'll move on when the time is right. Which, in this case, might be soon, because that really clarifies things. It's the _subshell_ thing that confused me. It seems that there is no way to put commands into $PS1 without them being in a subshell. Great solution!

Comment: @EvgeniSergeev While the subshell is a part of it, you could easily move the output to `PROMPT_COMMAND` -- just to get bitten by `RET=$?` without executing another command when creating the next prompt. So, no, it's not just the subshell, but it contributes.